# How to search for a file through the whole system by it's name in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, csv, path, fs

I want to search for a file on the whole system and get it's path. In my case, the filename is `data.csv`. What is the best way to do this in NodeJS?

Comment: Which OS are you using WIndows, MacOs or Linux or it could be anything?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara It could be anything.